# Big joins or multiple fetches most efficent?

Tags: php, sql, performance

I understand that multiple variables are part of this equation like number of tables, number of columns, number of returned rows, used indexes etc. But if we speak overall

Is more efficient to run a query with multiple (say 5+) joins where most of the tables will contain rows with information corresponding to rows in the main table and the returned result would be in the 20.000 rows range. For the sake of argument let's say the first table would contain users with a creation date and it's on this date we decide the users to pick out. The other tables contain stuff such as session information, user notes etc. All users should be picked out but depending on the values of fields in the secondary tables we might ignore the session data for one user and do some work with the session data on another user when we go through the results. This way we would get all needed data in one query but might get some redundant data for some users at the same time.

Or would it be more efficient to pick the users by date and when iterating the results we fetch data from the other tables per user when it's necessary?

Let's say that the work on the returned rows is done within PHP5+.

Comment: "If we speak overall", we can't really answer this question. You appear to be seeking a *specific* answer to a *generalized* question. That's not possible.

Comment: @Andrew: Oh, that *is* possible. What isn't possible is a *correct* specific answer to a general question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll say, do a benchmark.

It will depends on the frequency of "when it's necessary". If you need the extra date for 10% of the users, the seconde approach will be better I think. If you need them for 90%, it will be better to retrieve everything in one big query.

Answer (score 1):

Big join.

I can cite absolutely no evidence to back that up. I do speak from some experience, though: in the system i work with, we do millions of little tiny simple queries, rather than a few big ones, and all the data-intensive work takes ages. For example, it takes an hour to load data that a direct SQL load can do in a couple of minutes. The per-query cost completely dominates the equation.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have the proper indexes *(which will help a lot, when it comes to joins)*, one single SQL query, even a bit complex, will probably be faster than several queries, which will each imply an exchange between PHP and the MySQL server.

*(But, of course, the only way to know for sure what applies the best in your specific situation is to test both solutions, benchmarking them !)*